# How to prevent anchor default in dynamic ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wener/fsNUg/)

According to [ng/directive/a](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/a.js),to prevent the anchor route is `<a></a>` or `<a href=""></a>`,and yes, it works but not for dynamic content.In the demo above show the generated anchor with no `href` still cause the anchor route.

What can I do to prevent the anchor reload or route ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<a href="{{url || ''}}">
```

try:

```
<a href="{{url || 'javascript:void(0)'}}">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NacVf/)

Comment: For dynamic URL's wouldn't it be better to set the default href to `javascript:void(0)`, then use the `ng-href` directive?

Comment: @drew_w Should be tried out. Not sure, `href` and `ng-href` could be used at the same time.

Comment: According to http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref, `ng-href` should be used with interpolated expressions

Comment: The `href` would be used until angular renders the element. That is one of the purposes of the `ng-href`, `ng-style`, `ng-src` (etc) family of directives. Since they aren't rendered when the page loads, at least everything will still have valid values.

Comment: @drew_w Yes, I know the differences of `href` and `ng-href`. However, I don't think, the problem of the OP is related to that.

Comment: @Engineer I agree. Just making a note for future "stackers" that come along and find this answer : )

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways I have found for this that is also compatible with older browsers is:

```
<a href="javascript:void()"></a>
```

Some people will add a "0" ending up with `javascript:void(0)` as the call. Either way works well. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='javascript:;'></a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void();"></a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
```

**or by css**

```
a {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

or

```
a {}
```